# Slicing a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a class in C# that has a dictionary (`bigDict`) it gets from a JSON file. `bigDict` maps a string to a big data structure. From this, I want to create another dictionary (`smallDict`) that maps each string from the key to just one element (a string) in `bigDict`'s data structure value.

I've tried to use get and set to create `smallDict`. I was able to successfully use `get`, but I'm stuck at `set`.

```
class myClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, SomeStruct> bigDict{ get; set; } /*get and set from a JSON file*/

    public virtual Dictionary<string, string> smallDict
    {
        get => bigDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ElemFromStruct);   //works fine

        set => smallDict.ToDictionary.update(key , value); //doesn't work fine
    }
}
```

As a result of not being able to set properly, I'm getting `property or indexer cannot be assigned to, is readonly` errors in some pre-existing test cases (I'm refactoring code)

Comment: What is `ToDictionary.update()` supposed to mean? It's telling me that ToDictionary is a method, which is not valid in the given context. Also... it looks to me as if the getter returns a temporary object. Your setter calls the getter, gets the temp, and does something to that temporary object. Why? Also, `key` is undefined.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah, it might not be. I'm quite new to C# so I was just trying some stuff out. Probably the way I wrote set is completely wrong

Comment: I guess, for readability, testability, and maintainability you shouldn't be doing this. Create separate class, encapsulate all your logic inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a "one-off" type `SmallDict`:

```cs
    public SmallDict<string> smallDict;

    public myClass()
    {
        smallDict = new SmallDict<string>(bigDict);
    }
```

```cs
    class SmallDict<TKey>
    {
        public readonly Dictionary<TKey, SomeStruct> BigDict;

        public SmallDict(Dictionary<TKey, SomeStruct> bigDict)
        {
            BigDict = bigDict;
        }

        public string this[TKey key]
        {
            get => BigDict[key].ElemFromStruct;
            set {
                var obj = BigDict[key];
                obj.ElemFromStruct = value;
                BigDict[key] = obj;
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(smallDict["key1"]); // Equivalent to printing bigDict[key].ElemFromStruct
smallDict["key1"] = "new value";      // Equivalent to bigDict[key].ElemFromStruct = "new value"
```

It's a mere wrapper around a dictionary, so if you want more methods than plain indexing, you'll have to do all the plumbing manually.

### Genericity

Notice how `SmallDict` only works for dictionaries of `SomeStruct`...

I would have written a generic **DictionarySlice** class, but any attempt at actual genericity is thwarted by C#'s rigid type system: there is no sastisfying way to genericly tell which property to slice on.

*Possible solutions:*

- Pass *getters* and *setters* as lambdas -- sure you can do that, you would have more code in your lambdas than in your actual class, mind you. It could be useful if you need to slice on many different properties.
- Make `SomeStruct` implement `IGetSetElemFromStruct` which the generic class would use -- not terribly elegant and potentially extremely cumbersome if you have many properties to slice on.
- Reflection -- included for completeness, but won't expand on it...

### Large structures

**Avoid** large structs; and more importantly **avoid mutable structs**, which are universally considered a [Very Bad Thing(TM)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/) in C#. *From [Microsoft's design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct), emphasis mine:*

> In general, structs can be very useful but should only be used for **small**, single, **immutable** values that will not be boxed frequently.

```
set {
    var obj = BigDict[key];
    obj.ElemFromStruct = value;
    BigDict[key] = obj;
}
```

Notice that in the setter above, I get a copy of the struct, modify it, and copy it back to the dictionary... not great. If it's gonna be large, do yourself a favor and **use a `class`**. You would then simply write:

```
set { BigDict[key].ElemFromStruct = value; }
```

### Non-trivial operations in properties get/set

This is about the code you wrote as an example:

```
public virtual Dictionary<string, string> smallDict
{
    get => bigDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ElemFromStruct);   //works fine
```

**Avoid them as much as possible**. There is no definite line saying what can go in properties getters/setters, but creating and populating a dictionary in a `get` is simply way too much by any reasonable standard: imagine if you had to doubt *every* property access.

### Maybe don't use this *at all*

This solution is the best I could come up with, but it's clunky and not terribly useful. You have to judge for yourself depending on your use-case, but generally **accessing/mutating `bigDict[key].ElemFromStruct` directly would be better**.

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent answer, @hugo! This worked for me. And you're right that I probably shouldn't be doing this, but it would be too much to refactor everything to use `bigDict` so I have to do the slice thingy

Comment: As long as you know what you're doing :) Your question highlights one "shortcoming" of the C# type system -- this would have been an easy thing, say, in Javascript!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to create a `Dictionary<string, SomeStruct>` from a `Dictionary<string, string>`. In order to do this, you'd need to create an instance of the struct from the string Value. It can be done, but this means the `SomeStruct` value will only have the single property (`ElemFromStruct`) assigned during the `set`.

Note that for any property, inside the `set` method, there is a `value` variable available that is the same type as the property (`Dictionary<string, string>` in this case), which represents the item that is being passed into the `set` method. This is used below as `value.ToDictionary(...`

For example:

```
public virtual Dictionary<string, string> SmallDict
{
    get
    {
        return BigDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ElemFromStruct);
    }
    set
    {
        BigDict = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
            x => new SomeStruct {ElemFromStruct = x.Value});
    }
}
```

If, however, the intent is just to provide a way to get a `SmallDict` from a `BigDict` (but not the other way around), then you can just remove the `set` method, since it may not make much sense to allow users to set the `BigDict` based on only a single string for each `SomeStruct` value:

```
public virtual Dictionary<string, string> SmallDict
{
    get
    {
        return BigDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ElemFromStruct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rufus L. This does fix my problems. But you are right that I'd rather now allow modification of `bigDict` from `smallDict`. Is there any way I can genuinely create a sliced dictionary from `bigDict`? Instead of a temporary type that gets/sets from `bigDict`. I tried doing it in a constructor but that didn't work because the JSON {get; set;} was not implemented before the creation of `smallDict` leading to an empty `smallDict`

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"Is there any way I can genuinely create a sliced dictionary from `bigDict`? "* What is wrong with the code above? What needs to be changed?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Rufus L. I guess I just want methods to be able to update or add to `smallDict` directly as though it were a normal dictionary instead of having `smallDict` pass the input on to `bigDict`.

Comment: It *is* a "normal" dictionary. If it doesn't need to be related to `bigDict` (i.e. you can update or add to it directly, without `bigDict`), then just expose it as it's own property. Then clients can do `smallDict.Add("someKey", "someValue");`.

Comment: Do something like 
```set 
{ 
    smallDict = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value); 
}
```
?

Comment: So, I figured out that's a bad idea (goes into inf loop). Best to do it as @Rufus L suggested with a check to make sure the key doesn't already exist. If it does, we `Update`. If it doesn't, we `Add`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of small dict is. Probably there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do here.